# How to use String split[]

Tags: ruby, string, input, split

String is Ticket-178(Good) Like this..

I wanna split 178, Good this split....

What can I do?

Ticket-178(Bad)

I wanna split and input Like this.

178 Is input the A variable

Bad Is input the B variable..

Comment: Can you include some code? "Ticket-178" is that the string? What is Bad, I don't understand. Do you want "Ticket-178" => 178 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
test1 = "Ticket-178(Good)"
test2 = "Ticket-178(Bad)"

def parse_ticket(str)
   str.match(/(\d+)\((\w+)\)/) do |match|
     return [match[1],match[2]]
 end
end

parse_ticket test1 # => ["178", "Good"]
parse_ticket test2 # => ["178", "Bad"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
string  = 'Ticket-178(Bad)'

matches = /(\d+)\((.+)\)/.match(string)
matches[1] # => "178"
matches[2] # => "Bad"
```

Comment: Thank you Sir.
Code is Simple and also working perfectly!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `split`:

```
a = "Ticket-178(Bad)"
res = a.split(/\(|\)/)
#=> ["Ticket-178", "Bad"]
first_val = res.first.scan(/Ticket-(.*)/)[0][0]
#=> "178"
sec_val = res.last
#=> "Bad"
```

Though using scan directly as in @spikermann's answer is a much better way to do this.